# QueryDSL inner join: path expected for join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to create a simple query with an inner join syntax in QueryDSL but it keeps failing with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select distinct card
from com.db.entities.Transaction transaction
  inner join Card card with transaction.card.id = card.id]
```

The query I'm using is this.

```
    private List<Card> getAllCardsInvolvedInTransactionsQuery(JPAQuery q) {

        return q
                .from(transaction)
                .innerJoin(card)
                .on(transaction.card.id.eq(card.id))
                .distinct()
                .list(card);


//      return entityManager.createNamedQuery(
//              "SELECT DISTINCT Card FROM Transaction AS t INNER JOIN Card AS c ON t.card.id=c.id",
//              Card.class).getResultList();
    }
```

The commented code is what I'm trying to achieve with QueryDSL. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You should you paths and aliases in querydsl statements.

```
QCard card = new QCard("card");
return q
    .from(transaction)
    .innerJoin(transaction.card, card)
    .distinct()
    .list(card);
```

As specified in the documentation - http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html, see chapter 2.1.7.

Alternatively, I think it is possible to write the query in a more concise way, like this

```
return q
    .from(transaction)
    .innerJoin(transaction.card)
    .distinct()
    .list(transaction.card)
```